# For my self referencing table query it can't compare a collection to an object or collection;

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

```
class Place(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'places'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)

    lat = db.Column(db.FLOAT, default=None)
    long = db.Column(db.FLOAT, default=None)


    parent_place_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('places.id'))
    parent_place = db.relationship("Place")

    branches = db.relationship("Branch", back_populates="place")


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

When I tried to do following:

```
p_place = models.Place.query.get(parent_place_id) if parent_place_id else None 
places = models.Place.query.filter(models.Place.parent_place==p_place ).all()
```

I get following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...

  File "./app/ecom_chatbot/ecom_conversation.py", line 127, in show_locations
    places = models.Place.query.filter(models.Place.parent_place==p_place ).all()
  File "/root/ecom/ecom_bot/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/operators.py", line 304, in __eq__
    return self.operate(eq, other)
  File "/root/ecom/ecom_bot/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 175, in operate
    return op(self.comparator, *other, **kwargs)
  File "/root/ecom/ecom_bot/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 1037, in __eq__
    "Can't compare a collection to an object or collection; "
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Can't compare a collection to an object or collection; use contains() to test for membership.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `parent_place` relationship is wrong. What you need is a `many-to-one` relationship.

See [Adjacency List Relationships](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/self_referential.html#self-referential-query-strategies)

> The relationship() configuration here works in the same way as a “normal” one-to-many relationship, with the exception that the “direction”, i.e. whether the relationship is one-to-many or many-to-one, is assumed by default to be one-to-many. To establish the relationship as many-to-one, an extra directive is added known as remote_side, which is a Column or collection of Column objects that indicate those which should be considered to be “remote”:

You should declare your `parent_place` relationship as such:

`parent_place = db.relationship("Place", remote_side=[id])`

> Where above, the id column is applied as the remote_side of the parent relationship(), thus establishing parent_id as the “local” side, and the relationship then behaves as a many-to-one.